# How to find QButton created with a loop?

Tags: python, qt, button, pyside, maya

in maya one creates a button with:

```
   cmds.button('buttonname', label='click me')
```

where buttonname is the name of 
the button object. At a later stage i can edit the button simply by calling:

```
   cmds.button('buttonname', e=1, label='click me again')
```

Now the problem:
i created a bunch of buttons in qt using a loop:

```
  for s in Collection:
        file = os.path.splitext(s)[0]

        # Main widget
        widgetItem = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layoutItem = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        widgetItem.setLayout(layoutItem)

        # Button
        button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        button.setObjectName(file)
        layoutItem.addWidget(button)
```

How can i call/edit one of them using the button name?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already have access to their parent widget, you can find them by `findChild` method.

In C++ syntax, it would be something like this:

```
QPushButton *button = parentWidget->findChild<QPushButton *>("button1");
```

where `button1` is the name of that button.

Comment: Thanks Frogatto,
but each button is added to it's own widget?! See code in first post...

Comment: @Digidim No problem. If button names are unique, you can call this method on their common root widget.

Comment: based on that example (https://github.com/PySide/Examples/blob/master/examples/layouts/flowlayout.py) i use a custom flowlayout.

So i first look inside this widget for the "button widget" and then inside the "button widget" for the button itself?

       buttonWidget = flowLayout.findChild(QtWidgets.QWidget(), buttonName)

gives me none :(

Comment: ok - got it working now! Was looking in the wrong widget...

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @frogatto I need python way to do that